# Second Operand in MOV instruction

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, cpu-registers, instructions, mov

```
MOV R19,R18
```

We know that the data in Register R18 will **move** to R19 which is called the **destination register**.
My question is, what happens to R18 here after that?
  Does it become blank?
  Does it become Zero?
  Does it still contain the date it previously had, meaning that both R19 and R18 will now have the same data?

Comment: `mov` is always just a copy, not like C++ `std::move`, in any ISA, so unlike almost any other assembly question, this is answerable even though you didn't specify an architecture.

Comment: There is no such thing as blank in typical architectures (although you forgot to specify yours). It is also normally not useful to zero the source. So it's case #3: both R19 and R18 will now have the same data.

Comment: `R18` will still contain the value it previously had.